# set Coordinator Layout to "ONLY" snap toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout, coordinator-layout

This is my main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

I want to set the toolbar to snap mode but with this code , Coordinator Layout also shifts viewpager with toolbar.

I want same effect as play store actionbar.